# Gradle Build Error : aidl.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

this is my build.gradle file:

[click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENTbh.png)

and my error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\dev\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Could be a problem with your sdk build tools. Open your sdk manager(android studio) and uninstall the old SDK build tools 22.0.1. Now install the latest build tools such as 23.x.x and reinstall the build tool 22.0.1. I hope this helps.

Comment: the last one exist int my system but because of some problems i can't use it.

Comment: Run gradlew assemble --info and post the stacktrace

Comment: Please post the full error this is not enough information, clearly its failing to compile an AIDL file so my first effort would be to review all the `.aidl` files to make sure they are correct.

Comment: aidl error.in my opinion, usually bacsuse of AIDL‘s import including something that doesn’t exist in our project . Due IDE won't warn us .aidl‘s coding error, so we need check our .aidl file firstly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run Gradle with debug enabled (e.g. `gradlew build --debug`) to see the actual reason.

Common issues include:

- Package doesn't match manifest
- Multiple methods with the same method name (aidl doesn't support this as far as I can tell)

Comment: I got the same error after changing my package name. After lot of searches reached at the following conclusion.
Refactoring can't update package name in aidl files usually located at following path src/main/aidl/<app.your-package-name.api>  
Replace old package names in aidl files with your new package.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of search I found solution

Because of we copied IInAppBillingService.aidl file from trivial drive project into our project.

The package name of that file is not changed according to our project so we need to manually change the package name of IInAppBillingService.aidl file which is written at the first line of the file.

This solve the problem of **aidl.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 **

Answer (score 2):

Check your package declaration in your Aidl file.
Also if that doesn't solve then show complete log.

Answer (score 1):

package name under aidl file is not match with your original package name.Check your package name of aidl file.

Answer (score 1):

For me , it is because the `aidl` file name does not match the declared interface name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, upgrading build-tool version in app gradle script solved the problem

Comment: or delete the build-tool version in gradle script.(I am in Android Studio 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar error but it was in `aapt.exe`, 
I tried

1. clean/build
2. Invalidate cache/ restart

but after doing lots of search, I commented my all last added code and it starts working..
then I start adding small code and run it..

I found the following line:

```
android:background=""
```

After removing it starts working fine. I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just try create *.aidl in App -> new File -> new AIDL, then problem solved. So maybe the location that create the file does matter, FYR