# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to compile a project with Android Studio.

I had this error message:

> aidl.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1.

I updated Android Studio and SDK, JDK, gradle, build tool:

Android 2.3.3
Gradle Version: 3.3
Android Plugin Version: 2.3.3
Compile Sdk Version: API 26: Android 8.0 (O)
Build Tools Version: 26.0.2

And now I have this error message when I build with this command line `gradlew build --info` :

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aidl.exe with arguments {...}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005899/gradle-build-error-aidl-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: Thank you, I had already seen this post. Unfortunately these solutions dont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your folder where the SDK build-tools version is saved, in your case: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools then delete the folder 26.0.2, go back android studio, right click on the "app" folder and select "open module settings". Under "Build Tools Version" drop down, select the latest one that is available. When you sync your gradle file, it will ask you to install the latest one that is available, which is 26.0.2. Follow the prompts to install the latest build-tool version and it should work for you. This worked for me!